# iOS UITableView is drawing the cells strange

Tags: ios, uitableview, tableview, uiswitch

I have a UITableView that should only display a UISwitch in the first section, first row, but for some reason, the switch is being displayed in the 4th section. Also, when ever the switch is flipped on/off, a new UISwitch appears in another cell. It is acting very strangely. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    PrettyTableViewCell *cell = [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[PrettyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.tableViewBackgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor;
    }

    [cell prepareForTableView:tableView indexPath:indexPath];
    cell.cornerRadius = 10;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Push Notifications";
            pushNotificationSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] init];
            pushNotificationSwitch.on = pushSwitchState;
            cell.accessoryView = pushNotificationSwitch;
            [pushNotificationSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(pushSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }
    }

    if  (indexPath.section == 1) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Department Based";
            if (departmentBased) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            else {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
        if (indexPath.row == 1) {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Location Based (GPS)";
            if (locationBased) {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            }
            else {
                cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            }            cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        }
    }

    if (departmentBased) {
        if (indexPath.section == 2) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 2) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 3) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 4) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 5) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 6) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
        }
        if (indexPath.section == 3) {
            if (indexPath.row == 0) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 1) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 2) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 3) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 4) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 5) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 6) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 7) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
            if (indexPath.row == 8) {
                cell.textLabel.text = @"xxxxxx";
            }
        }
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Please learn to use the `else` part of an `if` block. Or use a `switch` statement. Better yet, setup an array of arrays of labels for your data so you can eliminate most of that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are experiencing the effects of cell reusability in iOS. You are using the same cell identifier for all cells, so when you scroll, an old cell will become available and dequeued from the `tableView`.

Try to set `cell.accessoryView` to nil right after:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PrettyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.tableViewBackgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor;
}

cell.accessoryView = nil;
```

Alternatively, pick a different cell identifier for that first `indexPath`, making sure you take that into account when dequeuing.

```
BOOL firstCell = indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 0;
NSString *CellIdentifier = firstCell ? @"CellWithSwitch" : @"Cell";

PrettyTableViewCell *cell = 
       [tableViewdequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[PrettyTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.tableViewBackgroundColor = tableView.backgroundColor;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, that worked. I am still trying to understand how exactly the tableView works when it draws the cells.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please don't forget to mark as the answer when you get a chance.